# How to Include multiple urls to one django app

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

In django I've an application 'users' which has a custom user model, a custom registration and profile views, How can I include the app's urls and django's default login and logout urls to the same 'users' app at the same time as below:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")), # Django's default authentication urls for login and logout views
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), # 'users' app custom urls for the registration and profile views
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

directly it is not possible. In your case:

```
# users.urls.py

from django.contrib.auth.urls import urlpatterns

urlpatterns += [
    path(users view1),
    path(users view2),
    ...
    ]
```

in main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', include('users.urls')), # 'users' app custom urls for the registration and profile views
    ...
]
```